# Can you receive the data/code from paypal when the payment for an item has been processed?

Tags: javascript, html, paypal, paypal-ipn

Is there a way to receive the data from pay-pal that comes out when someone has confirmed they have bought my item and the payment has gone through? I am looking to then use this data to remove an option for a size when the item is out of stock. By creating a bit of code; that say there are 3 items in stock, when someone buys an item the data from pay-pal then notifies my code to change the stock number down to 2 and so on until the code reaches zero and it then removes some HTML code, so that it is impossible for someone to buy the item if it is out of stock.

This is the basic idea:

```
var quantity_in_stock_S = 3

/*!!When paypal Size: Small. is bought!!*/ = quantity_in_stock_S - 1

function deleteOption1(){ /* deletes HTML option */
      if ( quantity_in_stock_S <= 0)
   {
     var S = document.getElementById("S");
     document.getElementById("mySelect").removeChild(S);
   }

};


window.onload = function() {
  deleteOption1();
};
```

As you can see I am not very profficient at javascript. But I am going to teach myself it to a higher level. I am just very interested in the '/*!!When paypal Size: Small. is bought!!*/' part of the code and if it is possible to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal's IPN system would send details of the transaction to a URL you specified, and using a server side language you could update the stock number stored in your database. If you had ajax requests on a product page, you could then keep checking the stock value and update the page as suggested.

I don't think you can just achieve this with client side code.

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell me where I could learn how to do this with PHP also can you then connect this to the javscript code?

Comment: [Paypal's own IPN example](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/GB/en_GB/files/developer/IPN_PHP_41.txt) is the PHP code to work with. I'm not quite sure what you mean by connecting this to the javascript code.

Comment: Thank you. To work with the code above `/*!!When paypal Size: Small. is bought!!*/`? So that when the payment is confirmed it does quantity_in_stock_S - 1